# What does this mean when I login and get a 'code' query parameter response from Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I tried running my custom policy for sign-up/sign-in from the [portal](https://portal.azure.com) using the 'Run Now' feature and got this:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com?code=eyJraWQiOiJmNXlKcktmRjZtRl9EaVd4b0d5Sm1pT0F1aXV2OEVYSHVuc1lmaXNwZlBRIiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwiemlwIjoiRGVmbGF0ZSIsInNlciI6IjEuMCJ9.oxgR8PRpiFRkCljn6J9qg1Ag802wZjbFkP92d-UitjRpfF3fpk0K_Dc71aLG3J0DXvpGWAZGh80HHdgjNh61C0PnKWahLwShMJGlDo5CXvePbh0E416-OmHGtWG7wiEeLamXe1ZZCR1v6rtqfRKH6rZubV7wNH6Fmvbi00y-fUh_BVWo9Pr6WqQAjHGYyUCt30cEgwJbWR3v8vpn2QzKpDjeNt0jBC8tsjyZZ1omE7omtEgmtSH-wUE4EXYFwTpofDo7yiL7TDKU6RIm1-8e8iExbjpyitmieBjuTId1GDMG6Ju3lmcL6DkQwQJETeKP1r7ScC-y6D7yDPkzX_rotg.06iXOYdfOkmIzEXu.TklqnriQ_OnivJ2zYq_MNj6jZganCvDPC1JSuwAO7pmzUFR_YHUephGXwQK51R7o2O8OLhm8T6D3JNNHTZR35oPamGIWbjp60KqZKcTKuX1lhmoAfpCCk34zbhEzST4oBQV9gRxVF0ZapCUHGFUd4Mhzg3oXGGmzZ5SgUEE7IvN2adsqPPFc9egBKh_hRFItcb4inK-7a493sD_rh1l6SOlbZQ_FyUKf7g8G9Qd62GnthVS0LNoFH_qz57JTgN79Hwg02JerV5TkWNTZWBCZI-pp-X2h9NLu2Sfa5Q59lmqjZaofo4_kBiQ192H02_i0M94sQMYvdO9gcDjpcfc8bfX67wBvb7dibo_WeOhdanyEnAaxbNy00mSdhXlY-lQcPf8iOk0mRSCeIgo-LPBTD8pZsmtYsluz5M47eBoB4KXPXCBggt9YxBxFJ_p-OP51PWRgjo0aiYUirtA9eMkxGd0eNMEeyUm2t7ztK-6PGIfVsgoV4yt-bgdOSkc.BWAsQ3x2JmxHVJAPMDfK6w

What does this mean?  I would expected to have been redirected to my url with the `id_token`.

This has happened a few times to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You will only get an `id_token` if your request asks for it in the `response_type` parameter**.

The 'Run Now' feature in the Azure AD B2C portal will only include `response_type=id_token` **if the Application you select in the *Select application* dialog meets these to criteria**:

1. **Is an Azure AD v2 App**. Apps have to be created via the Azure AD B2C *Applications blade* for them to include a request for the `id_token`. The picker also shows up v1 Apps, aka apps created via the *App Registrations* blade, but those won't include `id_token` in the request.
2. **Has Implicit Flow enabled**. By default, apps created via the Azure AD B2C *Applications blade* have this setting enabled, but it can be disabled manually.

You can check the URL that shows up in the Run now endpoint textbox to see if the given application you've picked results in the inclusion of `id_token` in the authorization request.

If you'd like this behavior to be tweaked (not show V1 apps, always include id_token, etc), you can always add a request in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv)

Comment: Thanks for the insight but I don't think it addresses what I'm seeing.  I used the 'run now' and got the above response.  I **changed NOTHING**, tried again and got the expected result of id_token.

Comment: What does the request look like in both cases? Does one include the correct response type and the other one doesn't or do both have the right response type?

Comment: I would assume both had `response_type=id_token` as it is there now.  I just open the custom policy and click run now.  Here's the current request when I click run now: https://login.microsoftonline.com/ebenefitsdev.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_signup_signin&client_id=5cd028ba-4d72-4b1e-92ac-599940e34a5d&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

Comment: I was able to check my browser history and find the request.  It **has** `response_type=code` as you suspected.  how could that be?  https://login.microsoftonline.com/ebenefitsdev.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?p=B2C_1A_signup_signin&client_id=35939828-c40c-4d68-9673-1d1f3a3f2ffb&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Febenefitsdev.onmicrosoft.com&scope=openid&response_type=code&prompt=login

Comment: I do think that each time you "Run Now" you are doing so with a different application selected from the drop down. You're probably not doing so intentionally but I've seen cases where the default selected value (application) is different for the same policy each time you open "Run Now"

Comment: Can you upvote the answer and flag this as answered?

Comment: The order of the app dropdown changes, see my answer, FYI.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me again and I figured out what is going on.  The problem is the order the dropdown changes sometimes.

[image]

So most of the time, the app dropdown loads like this:
[image: typical dropdown order]

But sometimes it loads like this and apparently, ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework will request a code:
[image: app dropdown order]